# Raphael map won't resize

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to resize the map created by raphael I ended up loading the SVG file coordinates and then running this function to create the map with the new region selected but I can't seem to get it to resize.
http://pastie.org/4319180

Comment: I accept for helpful or correct answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're only drawing the map in the canvas ....
try using

```
paper.setviewBox(xvalue, yvalue, resize-x-width, resize-y-height);
```

gives you zoom and pan functionality for the canvas , hope it helps ...

Comment: I also used paper.scaleAll(.42); to scale it down. This works good too and possibly better performance wise.

Comment: The idea of scaling it down is good ... but i couldnt find this function paper.scaleAll() in the documentation ... have you extended it ?? do your elements retain position and aspect ratio after scaling without giving the x amount and y amount of scale ? let me know, it could help me out aswell .... thanks.